# Unable to get specific tag using bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using bs4 and python 3.6 my problem is that there is a youtube search page and I want to get the link of the first video in it so I found after inspecting that id of that anchor tag is `video-title` and I used that parameter to find that a tag using following code also the link of every video's anchor tag has the same id as `video-title` so I decided to use `find` instead of `find_all`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup =BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=unravel').text,'lxml')

link = soup.find('a',id="video-title")
print(link)
```

but in return it gives

```
None
```

I have tried to get all anchor tags but that also doesn't include the tag which I want.

Can anyone tell what the problem is?

Comment: Youtube uses Dynamic data rendering means data is render by JS and also if you print soup you will not able to find `a tag` so you can try with selenium api or youtube python package

Comment: @Bhavya can you give details about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can use this **"\watch?v=\w+"** to get your links simpler than bs4 ☺

use selenium with regex for best results

Comment: Can you explain it in details

Comment: what he means is above regex will help you filter all url which contain `\watch?v=` in it. and like @bhavya said youtube use dynamic data rendering so using selenium or youtube api is your best option, you'll have to choose what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this assuming you have `selenium` and `lxml` install on your environment.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_tag():
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

  driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=unravel')
  # print(driver.page_source)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
  atags = soup.find_all('a',{'id':'video-title'})
  for tag in atags:
    print(tag.get('title'))
```

this method will return the title of `<a>` tag which have `<video-title>` as their ID.